# How to use List.Sort and Comparision(of T) to sort Descensing/Ascending?

Tags: .net, vb.net, sorting, icomparer

I have a `MyObject`; `myObjects as List(Of MyObject)` and a delegate `Comparison(Of MyObject)` that uses a lot of comparison functions (ByA, ByB, ByC etc) à la:

```
Shared Function CompareMyObjectsByName(x As MyObject, y As MyObject) As Integer
    Return x.Name.CompareTo(y.Name)
End Function
```

Now I can use

```
myObjects.Sort(AddressOf CompareMyObjectsByName)
```

How ca I use that to sort **Descending** or **Ascending**?

à la

```
myObjects.Sort(AddressOf CompareMyObjectsByName, ascending)
```

PS. Don't say I should write 2 different comparers...

EDIT
@Jon Skeet

```
  ''' <summary>
  ''' Sorts a list ascensing or descending using a comparison delegate.
  ''' </summary>
  <System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()> _
  Public Sub Sort(Of T)(ByVal list As List(Of T), ByVal comparison As Comparison(Of T), ByVal descending As Boolean)

    If Not descending Then
      list.Sort(comparison)
    Else
      list.Sort(???)
    End If

  End Sub
```

Comment: Take a look at [ReverseComparer](http://code.google.com/p/ngenerics/source/browse/trunk/Source/NGenerics/Comparers/ReverseComparer.cs?spec=svn315&r=315).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest way is to create a `ReverseComparer(Of T)` which can be constructed from an existing `IComparer(Of T)` and reverse the comparison. (Simply call the existing comparison with the argument order reversed - *do not* negate the result instead; that fails for `Int32.MinValue`.) I have such a class in C# already in [MiscUtil](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/miscutil), if you're interested.

Then you just need to sort by either passing in the ascending comparer, or by creating a reverse comparer from the ascending one.

EDIT: As it appears I'm not making myself clear, here's the extension method I mean - written in C#, but it should be easy to convert it to VB:

```
public static void Sort<T>(this List<T> list,
                           IComparer<T> comparer,
                           bool ascending)
{
    if (!ascending)
    {
        comparer = new ReverseComparer<T>(comparer);
    }
    list.Sort(comparer);
}
```

or for a `Comparison<T>`:

```
public static void Sort<T>(this List<T> list,
                           Comparison<T> comparison,
                           bool ascending)
{
    if (!ascending)
    {
        // Avoid capturing the variable we're modifying!
        Comparison<T> originalComparison = comparison;
        comparison = (x, y) => originalComparison(y, x);
    }
    list.Sort(comparison);
}
```

Of course, I would usually use `OrderBy` and `OrderByDescending` unless you *really* need to modify the original list...

EDIT: Further note: as suggested by Konrad, you might want an enum with members `Ascending` and `Descending` instead of a `bool` flag, just for clarity.

Comment: as you can see in VB.NET I use directly the function address as parameter. Now creating a reverse comparer should it mean that I need to create a "clone" function to each compatation? Say, I have 100 comparers (compareByName, compareById, compareByStuff), should I now write reverseCompareByName, reverseCompareById, etc?

Comment: @serhio: No, you create *one* generic reverse comparer. You can build your own `Sort` method which takes a comparer and an ascending/descending flag, and then calls `List.Sort` either with the comparer or using the `ReverseComparer`. To be honest, it's not clear whether you're *really* talking about `IComparer<T>` or `Comparison<T>` (the delegate) - using `AddressOf` suggests you're using `Comparison<T>`, but you talk about `IComparer<T>` in your question. You need to be clear about this in your own mind.

Comment: apparently you have reason this is the delegate Comparison<T> Ill fix the question

Comment: you have reason. So, knowing that I wrote 100 comparison functions, what should I do to add the ascending parameter without a lot of modifications?

Comment: @serhio: I've already explained it: you write a helper method (possibly as an extension method) which takes an existing comparison and a flag. You then call `List.Sort` within that method, either with the comparison already passed in, or a reversing version of it.

Comment: Actually I use enums, but I don't know why I sent booleans as parameters. )

Answer (score 1):

Taking Jon’s suggestion but making it work with a lambda expression:

```
myObjects.Sort(Function (a, b) CompareMyObjectsByName(b, a))
```

– no need to create a new method for each comparison logic; just call the respective comparison method inside a lambda with reversed arguments.

Comment: I wouldn't put that reversing logic in each call site though - not when it can be abstracted into a helper method so easily.

Comment: @Jon I’d generally agree with you but calling `Sort` with an in-place constructed wrapper isn’t going to be any shorter, nor necessarily clearer, than my code. At the very least it would amount to `lst.Sort(New ReverseComparer(AddressOf CompareMyObjectsByName))` or, using a method, `lst.Sort(ReverseComparer(AddressOf CompareMyObjectsByName))` which is actually *longer* than my code.

Comment: No, it would amount to `lst.CustomSort(AddressOf CompareMyObjectsByName, False)` or something similar.

Comment: @Jon Point taken. ;-) Although I’d prefer a `SortOrder` enum before a boolean parameter.

Comment: Yes, that would make sense. I'll edit my answer to mention that.